# Canvas InvalidateVisual() thread exception

Tags: wpf, canvas, bitmapsource

I'm developing an app that shows some images (with some filter effects) using Canvas.

I've a static class called `RendererBooster`. This class' `RenderImage()` method renders the image with given effects **WITH TASK** on background and sets the `MyViewer` coltrol's `_bSource` property with the rendered image. (**MyViewer is derived from Canvas**)

On the other hand, I've a `DispatcherTimer` inside the `MyViewer` class. This `DispatcherTimes` ticks **every 2ms** and checks if `_bSource` is NOT NULL, calls the Canvas' `InvalidateVisual()` method.

Everything is fine untill here.

My overridden `OnRender()` method just draws that `_bSource` to screen and sets `_bSource` to NULL. After that, I get **`Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable`** exception. Here is some sample code.  What can I do to fix it?

**RendererBooster**

```
public static class RendererBooster
    {
        public static void RenderImage()
        {
            MyViewer viewer = ViewerManager.GetViewer();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                unsafe
                {
                   // render
                    // render again
                    // render again ..
                    // ...

                    // when rendering is done, set the _bSource.
                    viewer._bSource = BitmapSource.Create(sizeDr.Width, sizeDr.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Prgba64, null, mlh.Buffer, sStride * sizeDr.Height, sStride);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**MyViewer**

```
public class MyViewer : Canvas
    {
        public BitmapSource _bSource = null;
        private object _lockObj = new object();

        public MyViewer()
        {
            DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
            dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2);
            dt.Tick += dt_Tick;
            dt.Start();
        }

        void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_bSource == null)
                return;

            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            lock (_lockObj)
            {
                dc.DrawImage(_bSource, new System.Windows.Rect(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0), new System.Windows.Size(ActualWidth, ActualHeight)));
                _bSource = null;
                // this is the line that i get the exception
                //Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than its parent Freezable
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** Why I'm doing the rendering work on an other function / class? Because rendering takes 3-4 seconds. If I render inside the OnRender() method, UIThread freezes the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BitmapSource` class inherits `Freezable`, which in turn inherits `DependencyObject`. As you know, `DependencyObject`s have thread affinity (because they inherit `DispatcherObject`). That is, every `DependencyObject` first checks whether you are allowed to access it from current thread using the [`CheckAccess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.checkaccess(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`VerifyAccess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.verifyaccess(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

In your example, you create a `BitmapSource` in the worker thread (using a `Task`), but try to use it in the other: the `OnRender()` method will be called on the UI thread.

So, one solution could be to create your `BitmapSource` in the UI thread. You could use e.g. `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or `SynchronizationContext.Post()` methods for this. If you're using .NET 4.5+, I would suggest you to change your `Task` code to something like:

```
public static async Task RenderImage()
{
    MyViewer viewer = ViewerManager.GetViewer();
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // your rendering code              
        })
    .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // BitmapSource creating code
        },
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

With this approach, your time consuming rendering will be processed on a worker thread, but the `BitmapSource` object creation will occur on the calling UI thread. You have to ensure the thread safety for your unsafe objects, however.

Furthermore, I would suggest you to make the `_bSource` field private. Wrap the access to it in a property with a `lock` statement. With your current implementation, the multithreading synchronization will not work properly (you assign the value without using a `lock`).

```
// don't have to initialize it with null, because all .NET reference objects 
// will be initialized with their default value 'null' automatically
private BitmapSource _bSource;

public BitmapSource BSource
{
    get { lock (_lockObj) { return this._bSource; } }
    set { lock (_lockObj) { this._bSource = value; } }
}
```

You have to use this property everywhere, including your `MyViewer` class methods. Doing so, you will be safe in accessing the object in a multithreading environment:

```
void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.BSource == null)
        return;
    // ...
}
```

If it's too complicated for you, I've a simpler solution too.
There is one thing about `Freezable`s to mention:

> Thread safety: a frozen Freezable object can be shared across threads.

So, you just could freeze your `BitmapSource` object after creation to allow a cross-thread access to it:

```
BitmapSource source = BitmapSource.Create(/* arguments... */);
source.Freeze();
viewer.BSource = source;
```

Comment: Woww. What an answer :) Thank you for that answer. Works like a charm! thank you again!